# Receiving object as string

Tags: javascript

I need to access to some props within an object, but I am getting an object as a string, this object comes from LocalStorage, what should I do to access to that props in that object ?

`lobby: "[object Object]"` there is the object

Comment: How are you currently trying to access it? Some code would be nice.

Comment: If you're just getting `"[object Object]"`, then the actual object was incorrectly serialized and it's gone forever.

Comment: How is the object being *saved* to LocalStorage? If `"[object Object]"` is all that's being stored, you're out of luck.

Comment: Try with `JSON.stringify(object);` if you need the object as string

Comment: here is how I am doing it `localStorage.setItem('apogeLiveLobbyData', tokenData.lobbyData);` the I getting it like this `lobby      : localStorage.getItem('apogeLiveLobbyData'),` so, when I do `console.log(this.props)` , this comes up `lobby: "[object Object]"` @PaulRoub

Comment: @Michelem no, the object comes like this `lobby: "[object Object]"` so I don't need a string, I need the object by itself

Comment: You are setting the data wrong.... that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` stores strings. If you try to save an object, it will first call `toString()`, resulting in `"[object Object]"`.

You're better off saving it as JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'apogeLiveLobbyData', JSON.stringify(tokenData.lobbyData));
```

and retrieving it that way, too

```
lobby : JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('apogeLiveLobbyData') )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not store an object into local storage since it holds strings. So you need to make it a string to store and than parse it to get it back to an object.

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
localStorage.setItem('apogeLiveLobbyData', JSON.stringify(tokenData.lobbyData));
```

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('apogeLiveLobbyData'));
```